# Selenium only returning 20 elements from Instagram hashtag despite scrolling

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to log into instagram, navigate to the hashtag i'm interested in, then gather links to posts using driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a') then extracting the hrefs from the list of elements gathered.

I then scroll down, do some waiting, and try to gather again once the next load of recent posts has loaded.
However, it seems that no matter how I scroll or wait, the same 20 links are always gathered, and never more than 20.
Anyone know what I need to change to collect more than just 20 posts?

here is the relevant section of my code:

```
for tag in tags:
address = f'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tag}/'
driver.get(address)
time.sleep(8)
alinks = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in alinks]
for scroll in range(1,3):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 12000);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 5000);")
    time.sleep(5)
    #scroll up & down to re-encourage instagram to load the next posts if it gets stuck
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -4000);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 5000);")
    r = random.randint(1, 5)
    time.sleep(r)
    alinks = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
    slinks = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in alinks]
    links.append(slinks)
posts = []
for link in links:
    if str(link)[:28] == 'https://www.instagram.com/p/':
        posts.append(str(link))
print(posts)
df = pd.DataFrame(posts)
udf = pd.unique(df[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(udf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself, although I can't give an explanation as to why this works when finding all a tags didn't.

So I changed my method to grabbing the inner html of the "recent Posts" (using it's XPath to locate it), and then using BeautifulSoup to find all a tags within that.

goes like this:

```
        recentPosts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                             '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/article/div[2]/div').get_attribute(
        'innerHTML')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(recentPosts,"html.parser")
    alinks = soup.find_all('a')
    for post in alinks:
        links.append(post['href'])
```